# remove port no 3000 requirement from aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mean, bitnami

I have hosted my MEAN project over aws ec2 (mean bitnami hvm) instance. It is running on port 3000 and I am able to access my instance in the following way:
    `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.amazonaws.com:3000`

I want to access the instance without the port number (3000),  i.e.: `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.amazonaws.com`

How can I do this?

Comment: Just use `iptables` to forward port 80 to port 3000.

Comment: how and where to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run this port forward command on your EC2 instance.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

And your port 80 will be redirected to port 3000.

Comment: thanks it worked.. now a new problem is showing.. as when i am searching for my domain in google search. the result is shown as welcome to bitnami .. can you help me with this

Comment: That is totally a different issue and question. I am not that good with SEO and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Run your application on port 80 instead of port 3000, or run a proxy (like `nginx`) that allows you to map ports and paths as needed.

Comment: how to run the proxy? running application on port 80 displayed error

Comment: Is this the stack you are running? https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/mean/#which-components-are-installed-with-the-bitnami-mean-stack  If so then you may be constrained to the operations supported there "for security reasons".